# How to sync android phones to a database in the same network?

Tags: android

I want to create an app for android phones and I'd like to know if is it possible or how it should be done this:

In a wifi area with a pc that acts as server, the android phones with this app (connected to the same ap) should be capable to access to a database that reside on the pc (previously having done an authentication). And then, get all the information needed from the database.

Rather than being continuously asking for requests to the server, it could download and make a copy to the phone just everytime the application starts and log in to the server (this db to copy should not be much large).

As well, the phones could send messages to the server and get responses based on the requests asked.

What should be done on the server side? what database or databases should fit better for each case?, what protocol is the best for this job...

I'm totally noob on this and i need all the help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

```
final class ThRegister implements Runnable {
    Context context = null;

    public void setContext(Context ctxt) {
        context = ctxt;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        NRSynchronizer synchronizer = new NRSynchronizer();
        synchronizer.setContext(getApplicationContext());
        synchronizer.regsiterClient();

    }
}
```

on buttonclick listner or any action do the below

```
ThRegister synchThread = new ThRegister();
            synchThread.setContext(getApplicationContext());
            Thread threadSynh = new Thread(synchThread);
            threadSynh.start();
```

Comment: Well, i expected an answer that would describe it in a global manner. Just to give me an idea on how to do it.i apreciate it, but this code tells me nothing :S

Answer (score 0):

```
final class ThSynchronizer implements Runnable {
    Context context = null;

    public void setContext(Context ctxt) {
        context = ctxt;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        NRSynchronizer synchronizer = new NRSynchronizer();

        synchronizer.processIBMessages(getApplicationContext());

    }
}
```

on action try below code

```
ThSynchronizer synchThread = new ThSynchronizer();
            synchThread.setContext(getApplicationContext());
            Thread threadSynh = new Thread(synchThread);
            threadSynh.start();
```

den call the below function

```
public void processIBMessages(Context context) {
    setContext(context);
    getMessagesFromServer(context);
    NRSynchAdapter synchAdapter = new NRSynchAdapter (context);
    synchAdapter.open();
    Cursor cursor = synchAdapter.fetchAllIBMessage();
    int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
    if (rowCount>0){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        String content  = null; // based on message type may need to call getMessageContent(also)
        if (cursor.getColumnIndex("content") != -1) {
            content =  cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("content"));

        }       
        String headers  = null;
        if (cursor.getColumnIndex("headers") != -1) {
            headers =  cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("headers"));
        }
        if((headers != null)&&(!headers.trim().isEmpty()&&(content!=null)&&(!content.trim().isEmpty()))){
            handleIBMessage(context, headers,content);
            long rowId = cursor.getLong(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("_id"));
            synchAdapter.deleteInboxMsg(rowId);
        }

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    synchAdapter.close();           
    return;
}
```